# handlebarsjs get the value of the selected option dynamically

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I've been working with pug/jade a little bit and now I'm trying to build the same project using handlebars.

I have this iteration that renders a few options:

```
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
    {{#each categories}}
        <option value="{{id}}">{{title}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

A bit further down the code I need to render some items dynamically based on the selected item from myselect.

Any idea how I can grab it dynamically? Basically the same way like [onchange()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) works in plain javascript.

Comment: Are you using handlebarjs on front end or back end?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I'm using it back-end side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use any kind of tempting engine (handlebars, jade, ejs, etc). You cannot bind data after the response sent to the client. You have to write some client side javascript code to achieve that.

As an alternative you can use handlebarjs on client side. Follow this [link](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

But this may need to be used carefully, since you are using the same template engine on your server side.